# Does a lightweight markup language library for Android exist?

Tags: java, android, markdown, bbcode, creole

Suppose I want to **render/present** a text transmitted in the form of some `lightweight` `markup language`. Are there any ready-to-use libraries for `Android`, which take as input text in a lightweight markup language and present it nicely? When I say lightweight markup language, I mean Markdown (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) or something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at:

[MarkdownJ](https://github.com/myabc/markdownj)

I haven't tried this.

[JMD](https://github.com/cletus/jmd/downloads)

This works, but the latest build has issues with some numbers in the text being interpreted as entities; e.g. "The 39th President" becomes "The &39;th President".

[PegDown](https://github.com/sirthias/pegdown)

<strike>This works properly, but in the rather old 0.8.0.1 version I am currently using it's really surprisingly CPU intensive<sup>(*)</sup> - much more so that JMD.  It's dependent on the separate parboiled PEG parser (which also has a newer version than I am currently using).</strike> (Stricken based on comment below)

(*) The excessive CPU load seems to only occur on the IBM Classic JVM for the AS/400.

---

NOTE: I have used these only on Java VMs, not on Android, but I know of no reason why any or all of them should not work on Android.

Comment: Actually, PegDown will not work -- I just tried it. It attempts to generate classes on the fly, which will not work without a Dalvik-specific implementation.

Answer (score 8):

There's also [AndDown](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-anddown), an Android wrapper around the C-based parser **sundown**:

> By using the NDK with this C library, parsing speeds are nice and fast -- 5K of input can be
>   converted into HTML in about 1 millisecond. Also, sundown is a fairly
>   popular Markdown processor and is the brains behind GitHub-flavored
>   Markdown.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check [markdown4j](https://code.google.com/p/markdown4j/#Using_Markdown4j), which is a lightweight java library (and can be used in Android).